# put def function into Class: takes at most N arguments (N+1 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7

this funstion works well :

```
def create_layer(layers_list,position=0,layer_obj=None):
    if not layer_obj:
        layer_obj,created = Layer.objects.get_or_create(name=layers_list[0])   
        return create_layer(layers_list,position,layer_obj)  
    else:  
        position +=1
        if position < len(layers_list) : 
            obj,created = Layer.objects.get_or_create(name=layers_list[position],parent=layer_obj)
            return create_layer(layers_list,position,obj)
        else:
            return layer_obj
```

But when I put it into class, I got error  :

```
create_layer() takes at most 4 arguments (5 given)





class Test():

    def test1(self):
        self.create_layer(layers_list)


    def create_layer(self,layers_list,position=0,layer_obj=None):
        if not layer_obj:
            layer_obj,created = Layer.objects.get_or_create(name=layers_list[0])
            return self.create_layer(self,layers_list,position,layer_obj)
        else:
            position +=1
            if position < len(layers_list) :
                obj,created = Layer.objects.get_or_create(name=layers_list[position],parent=layer_obj)
                return self.create_layer(self,layers_list,position,obj)
            else:
                return layer_obj
```

What happened??

How can I fix it ??

Comment: Add `self` as as an argument to your class method `def test1(self)`

Comment: Post the complete traceback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pass `self` to `self.create_layer` when calling it recursively. This is done for you by Python when it calls a method of a class instance. What happens here is that Python adds another `self` to the front of your argument list, thereby making it one argument too many.